Program for maximum partial marginal likelihood estimator (MPMLE) of regression parameters
I have a system of equations of probabilities which looks like



where . And I would like to solve the above system for U_1, U_2, U_3. I would like to ask is there any package in R or python for these rank based marginal likelihood estimation? I have done a little digging but the only thing I can found is the following paper by Minggao Gu, Yueqin Wu and Bin Huang which proposes an estimation prodecure to do that: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X13001772
Any help would be appreciated.
